# React-native open apps

Tags: react-native

I have written a few apps with react-native and I would like to have a "Main" app to link to all those apps.

How can I open those apps from the "Main" app?

PS: All my apps are not and will not be uploaded to either app store or play store so app id or play id are not a solution

Comment: the only way I know now is to use Linking.openURL but my apps does not have an URL to link with

Comment: You will need a url or an app store id.  Its the only way.

Comment: So how can I create a URL for my apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  url in info.plist files and create URL for specific app. You can use Linking class of react-native to open the page.

there is demo for android and ios [Read this documentation](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/)

For Android you can use this link:

[Android deep link](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e)

Comment: How about Android?
I have added the code :

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="LinkingTest" android:host="App"/>

to AndroidManifest.xml but it doesn't seem working.
Have I missed any steps?